# Custom domain assigned to an App Service looks like it is not finding CSS

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC 2.1 web app with deployment to Azure App Service.

If I go the the native Azure URL for the production slot at https://eii-ps-web.azurewebsites.net, the page looks just fine.

But if I go to the custom domain assigned to the production slot, https://www.postalsteward.com, it appears that the stylesheets are not getting applied.

When I use the Chrome developer console, the stylesheets look the same, with the exception of the respective base URLs being different.

If I ping wither URL, they resolve to the same IP address.

I did a search of my entire solution to see if https://eii-ps-web.azurewebsites.net was accidently hard coded somewhere and found no results.

I reviewed the application settings in Azure for the production slot and they all appear correct.

Has anyone seen this issue before? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Both websites seems fine to me. All CSS files had been loaded with no issue.

Comment: Arg! Chrome file cache! It is odd because I have been moving between DEV and QA slots for weeks and this was the first push to PROD, but I must have used PROD at some point with an old CSS. Perhaps when first setting up the web app. Anyway, thanks @Kamran for checking.